# Can I use Yule's distance metric for continuous data?

Tags: clustering, scipy

I've been building  a clustering modelling for my large data set (3700 x 891). When I thought of picking appropriate distance metric, I've decided to compare all the distance metrics in scipy module with KMeans algorithm. With the prior information that Yule's distance is appropriate for boolean vectors, I was shocked when I got that as top on basis of silhouette value (refer the table given below).

Now my question is whether I can use this as appropriate distance metric for my data or not?

Also noticed that most of the top scorer are appropriate distance metric for boolean vectors. So I'm confused about what's happening around :)

[image]

It'd be great if someone clarify this mess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the *same* clustering each time, right? k-means? so it was *built* using squared euclidean. All the differences you see are artifacts. Never compare distances this way.

Comment: @Mousse thanks for your comment.Can you suggest what should I do to compare distance metrics so that I can pick the best one for my data? Should I change the clustering technique?

Comment: I don't think you *can* compare silhouettes of different distance functions. It's always apples and oranges. Consider Euclidean and squared Euclidean. They are essentially the same thing! But by any means, you have been clustering with squared Euclidean (k-means is a least-squared-deviations approach), so the *only* distances worth looking at here are Euclidean and squared Euclidean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Yule and most other metrics for boolean data does *not* generalize to continuous data.

I'm surprised to see 1 as the answer, but if you **look at the source code** then you can figure out that the scipy implementation for continuous attributes assumes these are *probabilities* in `[0;1]` instead, and assumes `1-x` is also in this range. But if we'd use e.g. the 1 dimensional vectors `[0]` and `[-1]`, they have "distance" `-1` if I'm not mistaken... So **really, do not use these distances except for binary data or probabilities in [0;1]**.

As a rule of thumb, **never compare different distance functions**, either. They have different scales. Euclidean and squared Euclidean are effectively the same, but because the relationship is nonlinear, their silhouettes disagree. So don't compare even these two - the silhouette says one is superior to the other, but they are effectively the same result.